# How to pass conditions to "for" loop command in bash?

Tags: bash, for-loop, ls, conditional-statements

I'd like to pass conditions to `ls` or `for` commands to do something like this:

```
for file in *.jpg OR *.jpeg OR *.JPG OR *.JPEG;do
done
```

I tried with `|`, `||`, `OR` and with `[]` to close conditions, but It didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is so easy than:

```
for file in *.jpg *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG; do
...
done
```

or:

```
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}; do
...
done
```

see here for more examples: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html

However, my first choice is always:

```
ls -1 | egrep -i '.jpg|.jpeg' | while read file; do

done
```

**Addendum TEST1**

If someone is worried about special characters, these are som test:

ls -1:

```
with?newline
without
with space
with?tab
```

for file in *; do echo ":::$file:::"; done

```
:::with
newline:::
:::without:::
:::with space:::
:::with tab:::
```

ls -1 | while read file; do echo ":::$file:::"; done

```
:::with:::
:::newline:::  <= ERROR
:::without:::
:::with space:::
:::with tab:::
```

**Addendum TEST2**

For persons worried about amount of files in a directory, these are some tests done in a directory that contains 62380 files with long name staring by "file...":

```
$ ls -1 file* | wc -l
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long <= ERROR
0

$ ls -1 | egrep '^file' | while read i; do echo $i; done | wc -l
62380

$ for i in file*; do echo $i; done | wc -l
62380
```

Comment: @tripleee: In my personal experience, I've had some problems with ARG_MAX and none with filenames that contains a newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}; do
    # Do stuff
done
```

This will likely be the most concise, readable, and maintainable (modifiable) solution.

As tripleee pointed out, brace expansion is only available in Bash (which the asker has specified), so in some cases others may need to use:

```
for file in *.jpg *.jpeg *.JPG *.JPEG; do
    # Do stuff
done
```

Comment: Even *more* concise: `shopt -s nocaseglob; for file in *.{jp{,e}g}; do` :) That's fairly unreadable, though, so I'd dial it back to `for file in *.{jpg,jpeg}; do`.

Comment: @chepner `concise: adj. Expressing much in few words; clear and succinct.` In this particular instance, with only 4 possibilities, I find your solution a bit overkill!